# Inserting element in an array of array in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, hash-of-hashes

Suppose i have a hash as below:

```
my @A=( 1,2,[[ 1,2 ],[ 3,4,5 ]], [ 6,7,8 ]);
```

How do i insert an array in the third element of the array above?
Third element here is an array of arrays and i want  to insert an array [9,10].

how can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `push` and a dereference (`@{...}`):

```
push @{ $A[2] }, [9, 10];
```

Note that there is no "hash" involved.

Comment: As of [5.14](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Syntactical-Enhancements) the dereference `@{  }` is no longer necessary.